My Android app displays nothing on real phone but works on Android Simulation
I'm developing a short and simple Android app with Java Androis Studio. One activity, one Listview, 3 buttons on a Constraint layout. Android Studio Jellyfish
The app works on debug mode with Simulator.
The app does not display (white screen) anything on true phone while debugging with Android Studio or while launching from phone.
Logcat only logs this :

Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.simpleapp.memoraise2/.MainActivity }
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:37247', transport: 'socket'

I already developed app using previous release of AndroidStudio (Dolphin), but it is 1st time with Jellyfish release.
I tried to move that app to an old PC with Dolphin but it cannot compile due to AGP release.
I tried to create a new project on that PC with Dolphin and copy/paste main_activity.java code, activity_main.xml and strings but it cannot build with a lot of problems due to compilesdk and build gradle plugin compatibility I cannot fix
I tried to decrease targetSDK (from 34 to 32 to follow previous app I developped with that phone). Nothing
==> I re-developp same app with the old Dolphin Studio on old PC.
It works.
I moved the folder of app into new PC with Jellyfish. Nothing better.
